# Automatically sending an invoice in Magento after a Successful order

Tags: php, magento

I’m trying to get Magento to send the Invoice email to the customer (as well as the order email) after a successful order is made (including credit card deduction).
I’ve managed to get it sending the invoice by using an observer which calls this function:

```
public function sales_order_invoice_save_after($observer)
{
$invoice = $observer->getInvoice();
$invoice->sendEmail(’true’,’’);
}
```

however, no tax values come through! The tax/order/tax.phtml is included in the invoice email, which has at the top

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
$_source = $this->getSource();
$_fullInfo = $_order->getFullTaxInfo();
```

when I check _fullInfo it is an empty array.

All the other values of the invoice are showing, it is driving me crazy.

Anyone got any ideas, or a suggestion on a better way to send the invoice after a successful payment?